# Select unique records based on multiple columns checks

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres table `fetches` with below columns

```
id  |  status  |  company_id  |  created_at
-------------------------------------------
10  |  success |  2773        |  2017-03-14
11  |  error   |  190         |  2017-03-02
12  |  error   |  303         |  2017-03-01
13  |  error   |  286         |  2017-02-16
14  |  error   |  2773        |  2016-12-05
```

I am trying to achieve below result:

```
id  |  status  |  company_id  |  created_at
-------------------------------------------
11  |  error   |  190         |  2017-03-02
12  |  error   |  303         |  2017-03-01
13  |  error   |  286         |  2017-02-16
```

And this is logic I am trying to apply:

1. get all fetches where status is `error`.
2. if result contains any `company_id`, for which latest `fetch` (by `created_at`) is `success` then skip it from final result set.
3. `company_id = 2773` will be skipped because it's latest fetch status is `success`

Please advise how can I accomplish this in SQL way.

Comment: when you change what you want to achieve, please mark it as update. Now you have 3 working methods each doing what you said you need, but your new definition obsoletes all three...

Comment: I will make sure of doing that! and update this one too! but point #3 and #2 both points to what I said earlier but in a more elaborated way.

Answer (score 1):

try outer join:

```
with succ as (select company_id from fetches where status = 'success')
select fetches.* 
from fetches
left outer join succ on succ.company_id = fetches.company_id
where succ.company_id is null;
```

Comment: it took `10246 ms` locally. Just a note that, we have more `success` fetches and very few `error` fetches in db. So, I think doing this other way around should do the trick. what do you say, @vao-tsun?

Comment: if you don't want to compare table against itself, use window function, as @Gordon Linoff suggested

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select f.*
from (select f.*,
             sum( (status = 'success')::int) over (partition by company_id) as isSuccess
      fetches f
     ) f
where isSuccess = 0 and status = 'error';
```

Comment: the query is proving out to be time consuming and just to fetch few rows it is taking `10169 ms`

Answer (score 0):

seems you need  rows for company that have no succes in status

```
select * from my_table 
where company_id not in (select company_id from my_table where status = 'success')
```